# Compile-time logging source generator is not compatible with Serilog/NLog?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, serilog, serilog-aspnetcore

Compile-time logging source generator is not compatible with Serilog/NLog?

Can you anybody please respond.

Comment: Any update? Do you have any other question?

Comment: How to doing redaction for data in console.writeline(data) using this pacakge Microsoft.Extensions.Compliance.Redaction.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [github issue](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging/issues/197) and this [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/60968), we could find the issue has been fixed at the .net 7.

So the issue has been fixed and it compatible with Serilog/NLog now. More details, you could refer to this [merge details information](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/79038).